# Valid reason for creating a JMS connection and not starting it?

Tags: java, jms, tibco, tibco-ems

We are facing performance issues with one of our EMS servers, and therefore started to analyze the connections being made to the server.

Currently one user have created 142 connections to our server with **isStarted=false**, and approx 50% of these connections were created for more than a month ago.

What could be a valid reason for creating a connection and not starting it?

The EMS Java API Documentation only says this:

```
public boolean isStarted()

Indicates whether or not the connection as been started by the client.

Returns:
    true if the connection has been started, false otherwise.
```

Thanks for any further explanations regarding this topic!

Comment: quite possibly a bug. i dont know of any use case for creating a connection and then not starting it

Answer (score 0):

Probably the application is only sending messages and not receiving any messages. Messages can be sent even if the connection is stopped. JMS 1.1 Specification section 4.3.3 paragraph 4 says `A MessageProducer can send messages while a Connection is stopped.`. You might want to check the application for this point.

Comment: What would be the advantage of having a stopped connection in this case then?

Comment: I don't think there is any advantage.

Comment: One further observation is that non of the stopped connections have any consumers or producers, but the number of sessions per connection spans between 21 and 0. Why are there sessions but no consumer or producer on the connection?

Comment: You will need to look at the applications to understand this behavior. It's possible that applications are either in the process of creating consumer/producer or have closed consumer/producers but not yet closed sessions.

Comment: Session count and no consumer/producers for the connetions remains the same now, 6 hours later. Sessions should be closed when they are no longer used, as far as I know.v And why keep the connection open if there are no messages being sent?

Comment: You need to look at the applications to understand why sessions are still open when there are not consumers/producers.